# How to sum calculated results from a MAX query

Tags: sql

I'd love if someone would be able to help me on this.

Got some sample numbers, each has some couple of analysis and they might or not have an analysis replicated. I'm trying to search by every sample number the number of replicates of its analysis.

Here's an example of what the table looks like, with the filter searching for an specific sample:

[image]

```
SELECT MAX(ts.replicate_count) - 1
                                    from test ts
                                    where ts.sample_number = 72023
                                    GROUP BY ts.analysis
```

With this query, it shows the amount of replicates by said sample, grouping it by analysis. In this case, as sample 72023 has 2 analysis, it shows 2 results :

[image]

So now that I have each replicate, I would like to just show the sample number, and the sum of those results, which if we follow the image, it should be 2.

Got a query, but I'm not sure how to make it work properly:

```
select t.sample_number,SUM(SELECT MAX(ts.replicate_count) - 1
                                    from test ts
                                    where ts.sample_number = t.sample_number
                                    GROUP BY ts.analysis)
                       
FROM TEST t
where t.sample_number = 72023
```

A nearly close result I would like would be something like this

[image]

but with the correct info, obviously.

Would love if someone could help me out on this.

*NEW*

Got the following code, but I need to just show one sample number, and the result of the field on the middle, that would be the total amount of replicates :

```
select s.sample_number,(SELECT SUM(rep) as replicates
                        FROM (SELECT ts.sample_number, MAX(ts.replicate_count) - 1  as rep
                                from test ts
                                where ts.sample_number = s1.sample_number
                                GROUP BY ts.sample_number, ts.analysis) A 
                        GROUP BY sample_number),s1.sample_number
from sample s
JOIN sample s1 ON s.sample_number = s1.parent_aliquot
where s.parent_aliquot = 0 and s.sample_number = 42734
order by s.sample_number DESC
```

Here's what that code gives me:

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you mean?

```
SELECT sample_number, SUM(rep) as replicates
FROM 
(
    SELECT ts.sample_number, MAX(ts.replicate_count) - 1 as rep
    from test ts
    where ts.sample_number = t.sample_number
    GROUP BY ts.sample_number, ts.analysis

) A

GROUP BY sample_number
```

Comment: @dontknowcoding Great. Would you mind marking this as the answer in that case please?